# Custom facetkey missing in MongoDB Collection

Tags: xconnect, upgrade, mongodb

I am working in Sitecore 9.3 XConnect custom facet with MongoDB. I have created a custom facets model and JSON file and able to see custom facet attributes and values but facet key(Products) under content is missing in Mongo collection and I have doubt is it possible to create separate section for custom facet like content.

Facet Model:

```
[Serializable]
[FacetKey(DefaultFacetKey)]
public class Products : Facet
{
    public const string DefaultFacetKey = "Products";

    public int PersonId
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public centraldata CentralData
    {
        get;set;           
    }

    public Products()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Custom facet in MongoCollection

[image]

JSON Model

```
{
  "Name": "FacetSchema",
  "Version": "1.0",
  "References": [
    {
      "Name": "XConnect",
      "Version": "1.0"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model",
      "Version": "9.3"
    }
  ],
  "Types": {
    "Central.Provider.Sitecore.xDB.Facets.Products ": {
      "Type": "Facet",
      "BaseType": "Sitecore.XConnect.Facet",
      "ClrType": "Central.Provider.Sitecore.xDB.Facets.Products, Central.Provider.Sitecore, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
      "Properties": {
        "PersonId": {
          "Type": "Int32"
        },
        "CentralData": {
          "Type": "Central.Provider.Sitecore.xDB.Facets.Products.CentralData"
        }
      }
    },
    "Central.Provider.Sitecore.xDB.Facets.Products.CentralData": {
      "Type": "Complex",
      "ClrType": "Central.Provider.Sitecore.xDB.Facets.Products.CentralData, Central.Provider.Sitecore, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
      "Properties": {
        "Preferences": {
          "Type": "Central.Provider.Sitecore.xDB.Facets.Products.Preferences"
        },
        "Bookmarks": {
          "Type": [
            "Central.Provider.Sitecore.xDB.Facets.Products.Bookmark"
          ]
        },
        "FavoriteTools": {
          "Type": [
            "Central.Provider.Sitecore.xDB.Facets.Products.FavoriteTool"
          ]
        },
        "LikedContent": {
          "Type": [
            "Central.Provider.Sitecore.xDB.Facets.Products.LikedContent"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
  "Facets": [
    {
      "Target": "Contact",
      "Name": "Products",
      "Type": "Central.Provider.Sitecore.xDB.Facets.Products"
    }
  ]
}
```

Someone please help on this issue

Comment: Can you post the json model also?

Comment: did you add any value to the facet?

Comment: @Chris.. I have added the JSON  model